# executing functions from windows console - python

Tags: windows, python-3.x, console-application

I have implemented some logic through python functions and am looking for a way to calling those functions more efficiently. Is there a way to calling these functions from windows command prompt or python cmd like below?

python function:

```
def logic1(args)
    ...
```

want to call the function like this:

```
logic1(args)
```

Answer (score 0):

Import the file in the python console like this:

```
from my_file.py import *
```

Or

```
from my_file.py import name1, name2 ...
```

Now you can use these in the python console. Out is just the same as importing into files.

For calling the functions in the Windows prompt you need to separate each function into its own file and use [py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/) to convert them into executables. This may be an overhead of work though, depending on what you want to achieve.